# Springboot: SQL query runs fine in Microsoft SQL-server management studio but when I paste it in my repo method Intellisense detects errors

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring with hibernate (and JDK 17)

I have the following Query that calculates the distance in meters between 2 points:

```
SELECT v.VehicleId,
(geography::Point(4.40333979390196, 51.1743639872608, 4326)).STDistance(geography::Point(v.Point.STY, v.Point.STX, 4326)) distance
FROM (SELECT * FROM Vehicles) v
ORDER BY distance;
```

The first point is currently hardcoded since they are passed as parameters.
The query might also look a bit confusing but since my database type is 'geometry' instead of 'geography' I have to convert it first.

This query run perfectly fine in sqlserver.

The problem is I have to make it work in spring, and thus I created my own custom repository:

```
public class VehicleRepository {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   public void findClosestVehicle(double longitude, double latitude) {
       var queryString = "SELECT v.VehicleId," +
            "    (geography::Point("+latitude+", "+longitude+", 4326)).STDistance(geography::Point(v.Point.STY, v.Point.STX, 4326)) distance" +
            "FROM (SELECT * FROM Vehicles) v " +
            "ORDER BY distance;";

       Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
   }

}
```

As you can see I haven't even run the query yet, but Intellij says there are errors in the SQL syntax. It doesn't recognize:

- v, distance
- ::
- .STDistance

Is there any way I can suppress this since I know the SQL is correct because it runs fine in'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: Have you tried adding whitespace to `... distanceFROM ...`?

Comment: Why do you use a subquery for `Vehicles`? Why not just `FROM dbo.Vehicles V`?

Comment: Yes I have tried adding the space between distance and FROM, but still get an error

Comment: The subquery is because for another query I had to compare the distance between vehicles, and I copied from that query

Comment: Does IntelliJ understand the specific SQL Server `::` syntax? Also you could use a multiline string to make this more readable. Side point: why don't you use *actual* parameters rather than injecting. For example `(geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, 4326))...`